# The application is in break mode , aspnet core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

getting below error:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'ConfigureAppConfiguration' in type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.'

in Program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel().UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration().UseStartup<Startup>().Build();
    host.Run();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to include `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` as library into your project from Nuget

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the exact same issue last week and in my case the problem was that because of some some weird project references I ended up with version 1.x of the
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` assembly
and version 2.x of the
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions` assembly.

As you can see if you compare  [version 1 in docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilder?view=aspnetcore-1.0) with  [version 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.0) the method ConfigureAppConfiguration got introduced in version 2.0.

So basically you have an interface that specifies that there should be a ConfigureAppConfiguration method but the implementing class from the older assembly does not have this. I solved this by making sure I had matching versions of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions` everywhere in my solution.